# cannot marshal persistent entities into xml representation with moxy

Tags: rest, jaxb, glassfish, entities, moxy

I am trying to use a RESTful web service to unmarshal entity instances to XML tree structure. initially i got a duplicate named exception because MOXy could not resolve the property names and fields names of an entity.  So i moved all my annotations to the field level.  Now when i ran the program again i am getting an unsupported property exception

Bag class:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "findBagWithTagNo", query = "select b from Bag b where b.bagTagNo=:bagTagNo")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bag implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @XmlElement
    //@XmlID
    private String bagTagNo;

    // @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="bags")

    @ManyToOne
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "bags")
    @XmlElement
    private Passenger passenger;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBagTagNo() {
        return bagTagNo;
    }

    public void setBagTagNo(String bagTagNo) {
        this.bagTagNo = bagTagNo;
    }


    public Passenger getPassenger() {
        return passenger;
    }

    public void setPassenger(Passenger passenger) {
        this.passenger = passenger;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Bag)) {
            return false;
        }
        Bag other = (Bag) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
//        return "kharesoft.sita.Bag[ id=" + id + " ]";
        return bagTagNo;
    }
}
```

Passenger Class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id", "firstName", "lastName", "boardingNo", "seatNo", "flightNo", "dateOfFlight", "bags"})
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "findPaxByBagTag", query = "select p from Passenger p,IN (p.bags) b where b.bagTagNo=:bagTagNo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Passenger implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement
    private String firstName;
    @XmlElement
    private String lastName;
    @XmlElement
    private String boardingNo;
    @XmlElement
    private String seatNo;
    @XmlElement
    private String flightNo;
    @XmlElement
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOfFlight;
    @XmlElementWrapper
    //@XmlIDREF
     //@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="passenger")
    @XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "bagtag")})
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "passenger")
    private Set<Bag> bags;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Bag> getBags() {
        return bags;
    }

    public void setBags(Set<Bag> bags) {
        this.bags = bags;
    }

    public String getBoardingNo() {
        return boardingNo;
    }

    public void setBoardingNo(String boardingNo) {
        this.boardingNo = boardingNo;
    }

    public Date getDateOfFlight() {
        return dateOfFlight;
    }

    public void setDateOfFlight(Date dateOfFlight) {
        this.dateOfFlight = dateOfFlight;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFlightNo() {
        return flightNo;
    }

    public void setFlightNo(String flightNo) {
        this.flightNo = flightNo;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getSeatNo() {
        return seatNo;
    }

    public void setSeatNo(String seatNo) {
        this.seatNo = seatNo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Passenger)) {
            return false;
        }
        Passenger other = (Passenger) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "kharesoft.sita.Passenger[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

```java
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: Unsupported Property
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:183)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: Unsupported Property
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.getProperty(JAXBMarshaller.java:231)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider.writeList(XMLListElementProvider.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:181)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a bug that used to exist in Jersey.  Jersey used to only support the JAXB reference implementation and this was caused when Jersey attempted to set a JAXB reference implementation specific property on MOXy.

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: Unsupported Property
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:183)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
```

### Solutions

- Upgrade to a newer version of Jersey
- Upgrade to a new version of MOXy that supports that property from the RI
- Leverage MOXy through a `MessageBodyReader`/`MessaggeBodyWriter` instead.